# Set_post_thumbnail not resizing images

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm currently trying to resize all the featured images on my theme to 1140 x 500. I've placed this code in my function.php file

```
     if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
         add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
         // Default Post thumbnail dimensions (cropped)
         set_post_thumbnail_size( 1140, 500, true );
       }
```

And this code in my loop.

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check for feature image ?>
<div class="post-image">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div><!-- post-image -->
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the size itself does not crop the existing images. You need to regenerate the existing thumbnails too.

There are a couple of plugins for this, but I personally downloaded and used [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/). Install the plugin, and head over to `Tools > Regenerate Thumbnails`. There you can regenerate thumbnails for images that exist in your media library, replacing the old thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

very easy steps without plugin:

1) in your functions.php

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
         add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
         // Default Post thumbnail dimensions (cropped)
        add_image_size( 'banner_image', 1140, 500, true );
       }
```

2) this code in your loop eg. index.php, single.php etc.

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check for feature image ?>
<div class="post-image">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('banner_image'); ?>
</div><!-- post-image -->
<?php } ?>
```